# Specific values in R and Python

Tags: python, pandas

I worked with R very smoothly but now I want to work with Python. I have numerical values and into a data frame and now I want to filter specific values. I tried to find solution with other examples but unfortunately, I did find a useful example. Much of example are with strings not with specific numbers.
So first I want to show an example from R, these lines of code work very well.

```
  filtered_data<-filtered_data<-%>%
              dplyr::filter(items %in% c("2","3","4","5","6","7","14","20","19","23"))
```

Now I want to replicate these lines of code into Python and I try to do this

```
filtered_data<-source_data['items']==2,3,4,5,6,7,14,20,19,23]
```

So can anybody help me with how to filter these specific values in Python?

Comment: In Python we assign values with =, you will never see <-, in the worst case you will see -> for type hints. I agree with @timgeb, you should better study the Python's syntax first.

Comment: In order to help, we need to know, using a minimal reproducible example, what your desired inputs and outputs are. Also, what have your tried? Rather than "how can I do this?" could you describe the error or unintended result that you are getting? Additionally, if you would like help with Python, please give the example in Python.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO Look again. Now is clear ?

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO *"you will never see <-"* - [Here it is](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQ9dIwUZXwVDz/38A), works just fine :-)

Comment: *"I have numerical values and into a data frame"* - I don't think Python has data frames.

Comment: What about R ? Does are R have a data frame? @Kelly Bundy

Comment: I don't know R.

Comment: Please read the whole text and after that give comments.The  Data frame is for R.

Comment: The equivalent of R dataframe is Pandas dataframe.

Comment: @KellyBundy  at least I can say that <- is not an assignment operator in Python

Comment: But where is that operator? Show me into a post?

Comment: I'm just saying you should've told us about and shown us your kind of data. Presumably by adding the pandas tag and including a [mre] setup like Coraline did.

Comment: FYI - for filtering in Pandas check out [PYTHON : 10 WAYS TO FILTER PANDAS DATAFRAME](https://www.listendata.com/2019/07/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe.html).  Pandas also has an equivalent to R function chaining (an equivalent of R's %>% ).  Check out: [Using Pandas pipe function to improve code readability](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-pandas-pipe-function-to-improve-code-readability-96d66abfaf8)

Comment: Yes, an example might not be needed for someone addicted to reputation points and answering even the worst questions to make a guess. It's needed to make the question proper, though. Note that your question was closed for not meeting the site guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Pandas` and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
filtered_data = source_data[source_data['items'].isin([2,3,4,5,6,7,14,20,19,23])]
print(filtered_data)

# Output
   items
1     19
3      3
4     20
9      5
```

Setup a MRE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

source_data = pd.DataFrame({'items': np.random.randint(1, 25, 10)})
print(source_data)

# Output
   items
0     12
1     19
2     22
3      3
4     20
5     21
6     10
7     22
8     11
9      5
```

Comment: Because you forgot to tag your question Pandas :)